# saving files..all LOST after shutdown and settings

Tags: settings

I cant understand it...no matter what file I save, .JPG. music , text doc. or even session password for gmail...once I turn off the computer they are all GONE . ! is this a security setting that I have to change ?

Comment: Did you install this to a drive or running live off a usb or disk?

Comment: Are you sure you are not using some guest account? Or logging in into another account?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you logged in as guest/invited. Ubuntus guest accounts work like this, everything is set back after shut down. Files created as guest on Windows will be available afterwards, that's the difference.

To avoid losing files this way, you can disable the guest account, by typing in the terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T):

```
gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Add the following line:

```
allow-guest=false
```

It should look like this:

```
[SeatDefaults]

user-session=ubuntu

greeter-session=unity-greeter

allow-guest=false
```

Save and close. Next time you make login, only your created user accounts will be shown at the beginning.